# Regular expression capture decimal number ignore character

Tags: c#, regex

Input string:

```
----------------------
Test Id:         
Some Id: 718489  

        517.1[2] g  
----------------------
```

Expression `(\d+\.\d)` captures 517.1.
What I need is to capture 517.12 (without []). Is this possible with Regular expression ?

Comment: You can't remove the brackets from the capture. You can clean them out with a replace at a later point.

Comment: I see. I was thinking maybe it is possible to combine two captures into single one. I'm aware I can edit capturing result to remove "[" but that's not solving my problem. Regex expression is actually a parameter which can be changed later and capture should always be castable to decimal.

Comment: You could create two named groups and then combine them after the capture. `((?<Part1>\d+\.\d+)(\[(?<Part2>\d+)\])?)` => `var myDecimal = Decimal.Parse(rxMatch["Part1"].Value + rxMatch["Part2"].Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the whole number with the bracket and then replace the `[` with `string.Empty`:

```
var input = "----------------------\r\nTest Id:         \r\nSome Id: 718489  \r\n\r\n        517.1[2] g  \r\n----------------------";
var rx = new Regex(@"(?>\b\d+\.\d\[\d+\b)");
var res = rx.Match(input).Value.Replace("[", string.Empty);
```

Output:

[image]

Note that `(?>...)` atomic grouping removes the backtracking that we are not really interested in in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As @Vedran stated in the comment. You cannot remove the brackets in a regex, the best you can do is to end up with two captures.

But if your able to process the response this could solve your problem:

```
var number = float.Parse(Regex.Match(@"(\d+\.(\d|\[|\])+)").Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```